# Optimize SQL query that retrieves count of items over a period

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to better optimize the query in this function? I am wanting it to only make a single SQL query if possible. The code picks up the number of events generated over 2 weeks. Thanks.

```
def items_chart_data
    @current_student = Student.find(current_user.student_id)
    (2.weeks.ago.to_date..DateTime.now).map do |date|
        {
            created_at: date,
            item_count: Item.where("date(created_at) = ? AND student_id = ?", date, @current_student.id).count
        }
    end
end
```

Comment: did my previous comment work on your previous post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one query, like this:

```
items = Item.select('date(created_at) as date_created, count(id) as id_count').
          where('student_id = ? and created_at >= ?', current_user.student_id, 2.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day).
          group('date(created_at)').map do |item|
  { created_at: item.date_created, item_count: item.id_count }
end
```

To get the missing dates with 0 items into your array you can do this:

```
(2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.current).each do |date|
  date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

  unless items.any? { |h| h.value?(date) } # Check if date exists already
    items << { created_at: date, item_count: 0 } # Add item_count: 0 if not
  end
end

items.sort_by! { |h| h[:created_at] } # Put array in correct order
```

Note that adding the zero item days to the array doesn't perform any queries. The array `items` contains only 14 elements, so (especially compared to querying the database 14 times) this code should be really fast.

Comment: Is there anyway for it to show days with 0 items? I need a data point for each day (including 0s). My original approach was too slow as my database gets an average of 2million records a week.

Comment: If your database gets 2 million records a week I find it hard to believe there are days with 0 items... anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. I ran into some issues with h.value, but your approach gave me a good idea. I copied the activerecord to a hash and used "item_count: (items_hash.has_key?(date)) ? items_hash[date] : 0. Problem solved. Thanks once more.